# android.view.inflateException Android

Tags: android, android-view, android-inflate

I have created one java class and one layout with image button. When I set content view it throws runtime exception.

Error:

```
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oceans/com.oceans.LettersScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-02 17:46:39.558: E/AndroidRuntime(954):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
```

Xml Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/letters_bg" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
        android:src="@drawable/leftsignpost" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Java Class Code :

```
public class LettersScreenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.letters_screen); // error is here
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    }
}
```

So what is the problem?
Why it is throwing runtime exception ??

Comment: Have you checked if your drawables are ok? Have you cleaned your project?

Comment: yes i have cleaned my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried this code ...Its really working fine ... please check your Image and manifest file

Answer (score 0):

There are no any obvious problems in the code provided, should run? At least does for me (the drawables are mine, of course).

Check if you have the referenced resources `letters_bg` and `leftsignpost` in place. These must be under `res/drawable` . Clean the project. Try to provide the longer stack trace.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have checked but still it is throwing same exception.

Comment: At the end of the stack trace it must be another exception (cause) that is the actual reason. We need to see this exception to understand. The stack trace you post is too short.

Comment: error was coming bcz my image size was too large.. finally i resize my image. Now it is working good. Thanx for looking at my problem.

Comment: @zanky, if you think it's working, please, click on the big checkmark to accept his answer.